# How to fire grid double right border click event by code on delphi xe5?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe5, dbgrid

I m using Dev Express DBGrid component, I want to scale my column to fit my rows text so I used :

```
cxView.ApplyBestFit();
```

That works but somehow too slow, so I did some search and I found this post [on Dev Express Website](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B203532) but this don't help me much. So i started observing the grid interactivity what lead me to discover that if I double click all right borders of the grid one after other the grid will scale perfectly and quickly
as you see in the two pictures below :

[image: that was the 4th right border click]

then i continue to the last border to get this result :

[image: As you see is well scaled]

I m trying desperate to fire this double clicks by code but I lack experience on Delphi and Dev Express. So how to fire this event successively in all columns one by one.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will do the same as double-clicking the rhs of each header cell.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplyBestFits;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  try
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.BeginUpdate;
    for i := 0 to cxGrid1DBTableView1.ColumnCount - 1 do begin
      cxGrid1DBTableView1.Columns[i].ApplyBestFit;
    end;
  finally
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

However, I'm not sure that as it stands it is a complete solution to your problem.
In my test case, with 100 columns and 2000 data rows, it takes a second or two to
execute, which I imagine is much slower than you were hoping.  So it may need some optimization.

One obvious optimization would be to only call `cxGrid1DBTableView1.Columns[i].ApplyBestFit`
for columns that are within the client rect of the DBTableView.  Another might be to restrict
the number of rows in the dataset connected to the tableview to a lower number.  For instance, the following only calls ApplyBestFit to columns whose Left coordinate is within the width of the cxGrid.

```
procedure TForm1.ApplyBestFits;
var
  i : Integer;
  ALeft : Integer;
  ACol : TcxGridColumn;
begin
  try
    ALeft := 0;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.BeginUpdate;
    //  Process only the visible columns whose Left properties
    //  are within the width of the grid
    for i := 0 to cxGrid1DBTableView1.VisibleColumnCount - 1 do begin
      ACol := cxGrid1DBTableView1.VisibleColumns[i];
      ACol.ApplyBestFit;
      Inc(ALeft, ACol.Width);
      if ALeft > cxGrid1.Width then
        Break;
    end;
  finally
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think that should be ok  - I just have it in a ButtonClick handler for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi, the code is great and fitting well to column content but not the rows content of the column, WHY ? thx

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean by "not the rows content of the column".  If you can make a screenshot which illustrates what you mean, I suggest you post it as a new question (not in this one and maybe someone will know the answer.

Comment: MartynA when i used the same code without BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, I didn't get the same result WHY ?